# Remove margin bottom from all items on bottom row of grid of unknown number of items

Tags: html, css

I have a grid that contains an unknown number of items (the number is prone to change) with 3 items per row. I want to remove the `margin-bottom` from all items on the bottom row, regardless if that number of items is 1, 2, or 3. I've seen implementations like `:nth-last-child(-n+3) { margin-bottom: 0; }` - but this is always removing the margin from the last 3 items which is incorrect if my bottom row only has 1 or 2 items. Is there anyway to do this?

Here is an example to demonstrate what I'm talking about: https://codepen.io/jacksoncohen/pen/zYdWYBb

Comment: Would a negative bottom margin on the container itself work?

Comment: Please show an example of what you already have. You can either replace `margin` with `gap` or set negative margin for parent

Comment: Please show your html structure, how the row and their items are represented.

Comment: @rayhatfield unfortunately a negative bottom margin won't work for my use case.

Comment: try to use `.item {margin: 12px 12px 0 0}`. In this way the margin will be on the top of the items, not on the bottom.

Comment: This is just a guess but is `:nth:last-child(-n+3)` in your Codepen affecting the bottom three boxes? What happens if you just use `:nth:last-child`? Somehow I think that `3` is the key variable?

Comment: @Azu So simple and yet I was completely overthinking it... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is something like this:

```
.item:nth-child(3n):nth-last-child(-n+4) ~ * {
  margin-bottom:0;
}
```

So what this does is:

1. Select each 3rd element in the row `:nth-child(3n)`
2. Filter these elements by this condition `:nth-last-child(-n+4)` (you intersect all 3rd elements in the row with the last four elements) so now you have at least the 3rd element of the penultimate row selected and possibly the 3rd element of the last row.
3. with `~ *` you select all following siblings. The 3rd element of the last row won’t have any, and the ones of the 3rd element of the penultimate row are the elements of the last row.

There is now only edge case missing, and that is if you only have one row. But there you could do the same intersection trick:

```
.item:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(3),
.item:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(3) ~ *,
```

So your final rule would be:

```
.item:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(3),
.item:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(3) ~ *,
.item:nth-child(3n):nth-last-child(-n+4) ~ * {
  margin-bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: This really helped me with the same issue, thanks a lot :)